# How to scroll content that is being overflowed?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have a container of fixed width with list of elements inside:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.element {
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.element:hover {
  background: grey;
}

.name {
  max-width: 80%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: transform 2s;
}

.name:hover {
  overflow-x: visible;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  /* Value of translate is subjected to change */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="element">
    <div class="name">Short line</div>
    <div class="number">10</div>
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <div class="name">Short line 2</div>
    <div class="number">20</div>
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <div class="name">Very very very very very very long line</div>
    <div class="number">30</div>
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <div class="name">Very very very very very very very very very very very very long line</div>
    <div class="number">40</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Right now I have a few problems with this approach:

1. It looks ugly, because `overflow: visible` overlaps `number` container.
2. It shifts to the left and shows clipped text, but doesn't hide unneeded text. Just goes out of box.
3. It affects all elements, but I need it to affect only lines, that are clipped with `overflow: hidden`.
4. Timing is bad, because for very long lines it scrolls too fast and for not very long but still long it scrolls too slow. What I want is some constant scroll speed, so for different lines it would have different animation time. But I'm not sure if it is possible with pure CSS.
5. Sometimes scrolling won't trigger when hovering over next element. I want animation to cancel immediately.

Are those things possible with pure CSS animation?

Comment: The overflow isn't working because you've set it to the wrong class. Adding overflow to .element should fix that problem.

Comment: @ThomasTromp ```overflow: hidden``` works just fine, it initially hides long line as I intend it to. Or maybe you are referring to different problem? I tweaked some styles, so it looks better in snippet

Comment: It always takes 2 seconds to scroll from one point to another. I would have thought that's what you want. If it scrolled at say 10 cm a second, you could be waiting a long time for very long text.

Comment: @RichardHunter yeah, I know, but the texts are not so big, so constant speed would look better than constant time

Answer (score 0):

set this code in the name class to make the overflowed content visible by scrolling

```
overflow:scroll;
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, in some ways it adresses a lot of issues, but I can't take that approach

Answer (score 0):

This is just a shotgap  until more sophisticated alternatives can work.

```css
        * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container{
    background-color: white;
}
.element {
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.element:hover {
  background: grey;
}

.element:nth-child(3):hover .name{
  overflow-x: visible;
  transform: translateX(-35%);
  /* Value of translate is subjected to change */
}

.element:nth-child(4):hover .name{
  overflow-x: visible;
  transform: translateX(-130%);
  /* Value of translate is subjected to change */
}

.element:hover .number{
    background-color: grey;
}
.name{

  max-width:100%;
  white-space:nowrap;
  
  transition: transform 2s;
}

.number{
position:absolute;
margin-left:195px;
transition: 0.4s;
z-index:10000;
background-color: white;
}



.block{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    background-color: white;
    height: 1em;
    width: 1em;
    margin-left:-15px;
}
.side_block{
    top: 0;
    left:0;
    margin-left: 219px;
position:absolute;
background-color: white;
overflow:hidden;
width: 50vw;
height:100px;
z-index: 10000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="element">
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="name">Short line</div>
    <div class="number">10</div>
    
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="name">Short line 2</div>
    <div class="number">20</div>
    
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="name">Very very very very very very long line</div>
    <div class="number">30</div>
    
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="name">Very very very very very very very very very very very very long line</div>
    <div class="number">40</div>
    
  </div>
  <div class="side_block"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Has it's own problems. but still looks very promising

Comment: what problem let me see if could rectify it

Comment: Ideally .number and .block should be greyed too and issues about affecting all lines, timing and not always triggering are still there

Comment: @AlexanderZh.I edited the code This will work i solved issue about affecting the line while using translateX

Comment: But it still affects those lines, who are not overflowing

Comment: @AlexanderZh. for that you need to use nth_child() for those lines which are overflowing i edited the code again and this will work fine

Comment: the problem is I can't know for sure which lines will overflow. So more univaersal approach is needed

Comment: @AlexanderZh. for that you need to calculate the minimum number of characters(number of characters include spaces) that fits in the width and if it exceeds then that transformation effect will execute, and for that you need javascript or jquery and still i could not find a logic to how much % we should translate x as per the number of characters.The above answer is what you can make out of css In order to find which line will overflow you need to check whether the name class length >=30 that worked but i could not get the logic to find translate value for every line